# Start Java application from web-site / Java Web Start successor

Tags: java, deprecated, java-web-start

**How to distribute and start a Java application from a Website?**

**Background**

We developed a CSV-Importer in Java which inserts rows of a CSV-File into our HANA database.
The users who are supposed to use the tool are about 600 and we want to make it as easy as possible to use the tool.
I remembered Java Web Start which I used a long time ago. Unfortunately it is deprecated.

There are many discussions about how long Java Web Start is available.
But I do find little information about what to use instead.

**Current Research**

In search for a way to start a Java application from a website i found :

- WebSwing which is basically not a replacement since the program runs actually on the server
- There is a very interessting project which is an open-source replacement of Web-Start: https://dev.karakun.com/webstart/

**Also**

- What are people supposed to do?
- Do not use Java / What to use instead?
- What are other companies doing now

**Why is this question voted to be closed**

- this is a serious programming question
- if there is something wrong pls specifiy in comments so I can comply to the rules

Comment: Please only ask relevant questions, this is self-promotion.

Comment: JWS is not deprecated anymore, it is gone. Release Notes: "The Java Plugin and Java WebStart technologies that were deprecated in JDK 9 and marked as candidates for removal in JDK 10, **have now been removed**. ... Users can use jlink to create smaller custom runtimes."

Comment: @baileyhaldwin What? Selfpromotion? What about to evaluate if we can continue to use java or not? Why is it not a valid question?

Comment: *"What are people supposed to do?"* - Contribute startup capital for that project that you found :-)

Comment: I've started a new project to provide an "application store" like solution: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-jstore

Answer (score 0):

> What are people supposed to do? Do not use Java / What to use instead?

Well, not using Java is an option I suppose.

Another is to use a (classical) Java installer generator and distribute installers.  There are lots of them around ... as my friend Google Search will attest.  For example:

- InstallAnywhere
- install4j
- IzPack
- VAInstall
- Packlet
- AntInstaller
- NISI
- Launch4j
- InstallJammer
- DeNova

A third option would be to use "jlink" (Java 8 and later, I think) to produce a cut-down JVM for your application, and distribute that.

A final option would be to stick with Java 8 until a suitable (i.e. acceptable to you) alternative to JWS emerges.

Answer (score 0):

next to the WebStart replacement that is done by Karakun (https://dev.karakun.com) you can have a look at Install4J (https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html). This tool provides the possibility to create a native installer and executable (with update functionality) for your app.